# Where can I find a copy of Guy Jacobson's thesis "Succinct Static Data Structures"?

Tags: soft-question, ds.data-structures

I'm looking for a copy of Guy Jacobson's PhD thesis: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=915547 but I couldn't find it so far. Does anybody know where can I access it ? I really need it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.worldcat.org/title/succinct-static-data-structures/oclc/19364636

Comment: Did you ask your local university library? The thesis seems to be available in many university libraries, and I would be very surprised if you could not get a copy of it through the interlibrary services.

Comment: By the way, there is no reason not to include the name of the author and the precise title of the thesis in your question.

Comment: This question's title is misleading.

Comment: I edited the title and added Jacobson's name to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in USA and it's not in my university library.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Libraries at university usually have inter-loan arrangements, try asking someone in your library to request a copy from CMU's library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try [writing CMU](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/cs.html) to ask for a copy of the [technical report](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~clamen/reports/1989.html) version; Jacobson's thesis is technical report number CMU-CS-89-112.  No idea if this would actually work though.

It's also possible, but unlikely, that [Jacobson's advisor](http://www.scs.gatech.edu/people/merrick-furst) has an electronic copy.

As a last resort, you (or your advisor, or your university library) can order a copy from [ProQuest](http://disexpress.umi.com/dxweb), the entity formerly known as University Microfilms. [Sorry, there's no way to link directly; just search for "Guy Jacobson".]  A PDF copy costs \$37; a softbound paper copy costs \$59.

Answer (score 0):

you can find a paper copied pdf here.

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=63533

Comment: This paper is based on Jacobson's thesis, but it is not the same thing at all.